# pyspark equivalent of postgres regexp_substr fails to extract value

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to adapt some postgres sql code I have, to pyspark sql.  In the postgres sql I'm using the regexp_substr function to parse out ' .5G' if it shows up in a string in the productname column.  (I've included example code below).  On the pyspark side I'm trying to use the regexp_extract function, but it's only returning null.  I've compared the output from the regexp_replace function in postgres to the pyspark, and it's returning the same value.  so the issue must be in the regexp_extract function.  I've created a sample input dataframe along with the pyspark code I'm currently running below.  can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and suggest how to fix it, thank you.

postgres:

```
select
regexp_substr(trim(upper(regexp_replace(a.productname, '[,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-]'))), ' .5G') as A

from df
```

output:

```
' .5G'
```

code:

```
# creating dummy data

df = sc.parallelize([('LEMON MERINGUE .5G CAKE SUGAR', )]).toDF(["productname"])


# turning dataframe into view
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")


# example query trying to extract ' .5G'
testquery=("""select
regexp_extract('('+trim(upper(regexp_replace(a.productname, '[,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-]','')))+')', ' .5G',1) as A
from df a
""")


# creating dataframe with extracted value in column
test_df=spark.sql(testquery)

test_df.show(truncate=False)
```

output:

```
+----+
|A   |
+----+
|null|
+----+
```

Comment: Just check for the presence of `.5G` in the string.  No need for complex replacements here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if I ignore the " trim(upper(regexp_replace(a.productname, '[,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-]',''))) ", and just replace it with a.productname, it still returns null.  regex_subtr is heavily used in the code I'm translating.  also in this examples there's a ' ' before the .5G, so ' .5G' that it's trying to match.  the result is used inside of a case statement.  so the logic gets more complicated.  mainly I'm trying to figure out how to get regexp_extract to work like regexp_subtr.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `'.5G'` in parenthesis, not wrapping the column in parenthesis.

```
testquery = """
select
    regexp_extract(trim(upper(regexp_replace(a.productname, '[,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-]',''))), '( .5G)', 1) as A
from df a
"""

test_df = spark.sql(testquery)
test_df.show(truncate=False)
+----+
|A   |
+----+
| .5G|
+----+
```

Also note that you cannot `+` strings together; use `concat` for that purpose.